# Local variable in recursive call

Tags: python

I have a function that count the number that less than item in a binary search tree.It is working fine. But i just don't understand why local variable count can remember the total because each recursive call, it is reset to 0.

```
def count_less(self, item):
    """(BST, object) -> int
    Return the number of items in BST that  less than item.
    """
    return BST.count_less_helper(self.root, item)

# Recursive helper function for count_less. 
def count_less_helper(root, item):
    count = 0
    if root:
        if root.item < item:
            count += 1
            count += BST.count_less_helper(root.left, item)
            count += BST.count_less_helper(root.right, item)
        elif root.item > item:
            count += BST.count_less_helper(root.left, item)
    return count
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `count` locally to 0 at the start of the function, but then you're adding all of the counts from later recursive invocations to it before you return it back to the caller. Each later function starts at 0, but then adds 1 + the counts of the later calls.

Answer (score 0):

> why local variable `count` can remember the total

In fact, it doesn't "remember".

At each level of recursion, the value of `count` is derived from scratch, using the values returned by the recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass `count` to the recursive calls you make so that it can keep track of it and increment it.  Alternately you could allow count to be a global variable and increment it on each call, which is considerably less elegant.